# Retrieve latest data on top in firebase list view

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want in my android app latest data added to firebase retrieves on top in list view. Currently my data is adding at the end in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could save your data with a timestamp as a field on the object and then retrieve it with something like:

```
ref.child("myData").orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(10)
```

Then in your security & rules have something like:

```
"myData": {
            ".indexOn": "timestamp"
          }
```

To boost performance

Comment: but in my app i am using query ref.orderByChild("City").How to use timestamp with this.